# Run JavaScript from ScheduledTaskAgent

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-sdk

I'd like to use a JavaScript library from within a ScheduledTaskAgent on Windows Phone 8.  We use this library across our mobile platforms so we don't have to write N versions of it.

I thought I'd be able to do that with a WebBrowser within a ScheduledTaskAgent but I'm running into cross threading issues if I execute this outside of a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke and a System.UnauthorizedAccess exception (claiming I need ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT despite having that in my application's WMAppManifest.xml) when inside of Dispatcher.BeginInvoke like so:

```
    static ScheduledAgent()
    {
        // Subscribe to the managed exception handler
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
        {
            Application.Current.UnhandledException += UnhandledException;

            client = new WebBrowser();
            client.NavigateToString("<html><body><script src='https://...path to library...'/></body></html>");
        });

    }
```

Has anyone done anything like this before successfully?   I can't believe I'm the first person to want to run JavaScript from a background scheduled task on Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the WebBrowser control is not supported in a background task, see:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962(v=vs.105).aspx